# How to create tags from one content to another content using PERL

Tags: regex, string, perl

My **string_1** = "Noch befinden wir uns aber in der 1. Generation, so dass diese institutionalisierten Handlungsweisen nach wie vor durchschaubar und als menschliche Konstruktion ersichtlich sind. Der Institutionalisierungsvorgang endet erst im Zuge der <\i>Internalisierung</i> der Folgegeneration durch die (Prim&#x00E4;r)sozialisation, in der die kollektiven Wissensbest&#x00E4;nde als Teil der subjektiven Wirklichkeit verinnerlicht werden. Erst hierdurch werden die Institutionen als Teil einer absolut wahrgenommenen objektiven Wirklichkeit angesehen. Sie erhalten dadurch objektiven Charakter. Diesen Vorgang der Vergegenst&#x00E4;ndlichung nennt Berger/Luckmann <\i>Objektivation</i>. Der Eindruck eines menschlichen Erzeugnisses verschwindet. Die Institutionen werden als naturgegebene, unhinterfragbare und nicht ver&#x00E4;nderbare faktische Gegebenheiten angesehen, als kollektiv geteilte Wissensbest&#x00E4;nde. Die Autorit&#x00E4;t der Institution an sich, die sich aus ihrer historisch bedingten Faktizit&#x00E4;t ergibt, sowie die Autorit&#x00E4;t der Bezugspersonen, die gesellschaftliche Institutionen, Normen und Verhaltensweisen &#x00FC;bermitteln, f&#x00FC;hren dabei zu einem ***regelkonformen Handeln der Nachkommen (Berger/Luckmann <\sup>21</sup>2007, 62–72).***"

My **string_2** = "regelkonformen Handeln der Nachkommen (Berger/Luckmann 2007, 62–72)."

---

You can see the above two stings, that **string_2** contents are available in **string_1** but the only difference is HTML tags.

I want to match **string_2** in **string_1** and have to create/copy what are the tags inside in **string_1** matching area to the **string_2** contents.

Kindly anybody give any idea to solve this

Thanks
Vimal

Comment: Matching contents are highlighted...

Comment: is it possible to have nested tags?

Comment: Yes! something like this ( <a name="name1"><sup>100</sup></a> )

Comment: and the content between tags are never in string_2?

Comment: Yes! Thats what We have to create/copy to string_2 by matching it in string_1 without tag contents.

Comment: in simple, I want to create the <sup> tag in string_2 exactly where it is in string_1;  Note: in this case its <sup> tag but it can be any tag aswell

Comment: My idea is to split string_2 by space and then to join with a subpattern that describes possible tags.

Comment: thanks for your comment Mr Casimir, Im really new to perl, can you show any small example for this ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following script splits the search string on whitespace and then inserts a simplified pattern for random HTML between the words:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string_1 = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $string_2 = "regelkonformen Handeln der Nachkommen (Berger/Luckmann 2007, 62&#x2013;72).";

# Build a regex to match HTML interjected at whitespace
my $string2_re = join '(?:\s+|<(\w+)\b.*?</\g{-1}>)+', map quotemeta, split ' ', $string_2;

if ($string_1 =~ /($string2_re)/) {
    print "Matching = '$1'";
}

__DATA__
Noch befinden wir uns aber in der 1. Generation, 
so dass diese institutionalisierten Handlungsweisen nach wie vor durchschaubar 
und als menschliche Konstruktion ersichtlich sind. Der Institutionalisierungsvorgang 
endet erst im Zuge der <i>Internalisierung</i> der Folgegeneration durch die 
(Prim&#x00E4;r)sozialisation, in der die kollektiven Wissensbest&#x00E4;nde als Teil 
der subjektiven Wirklichkeit verinnerlicht werden. Erst hierdurch werden die Institutionen 
als Teil einer absolut wahrgenommenen objektiven Wirklichkeit angesehen. Sie erhalten 
dadurch objektiven Charakter. Diesen Vorgang der Vergegenst&#x00E4;ndlichung nennt 
Berger/Luckmann <i>Objektivation</i>. Der Eindruck eines menschlichen Erzeugnisses 
verschwindet. Die Institutionen werden als naturgegebene, unhinterfragbare und nicht 
ver&#x00E4;nderbare faktische Gegebenheiten angesehen, als kollektiv geteilte 
Wissensbest&#x00E4;nde. Die Autorit&#x00E4;t der Institution an sich, die sich aus ihrer 
historisch bedingten Faktizit&#x00E4;t ergibt, sowie die Autorit&#x00E4;t der 
Bezugspersonen, die gesellschaftliche Institutionen, Normen und Verhaltensweisen 
&#x00FC;bermitteln, f&#x00FC;hren dabei zu 
einem regelkonformen Handeln der <a sdj="asdas"><sup>saddfsdfsad</sup></a> Nachkommen (Berger/Luckmann <sup>21</sup>2007, 62&#x2013;72).
```

Outputs:

```
Matching = 'regelkonformen Handeln der <a sdj="asdas"><sup>saddfsdfsad</sup></a> Nachkommen (Berger/Luckmann <sup>21</sup>2007, 62&#x2013;72).'
```

Note: I answered your cross-post yesterday: [How to create tags from one content to another content using PERL](http://bytes.com/topic/perl/answers/956743-how-create-tags-one-content-another-content-using-perl).  If you're going to spam the internet looking for assistance, don't forget to check back to see if someone responds.

Comment: Hi Miller, Thanks for your Post, Your code works well but its creating only tag with content, they are not creating tag for the word already there in string_2 without tag

Answer (score 3):

You can try this code:

```
my @wordlist = split(/\s+/, $string_2);

s/([^\pN\pL])/sprintf("(?&sub)?%s(?&sub)?", quotemeta $1)/ge for @wordlist;

my $patterns = qr` (?(DEFINE)
       (?<sctag>   <(?!/)[^>]*+> )  # self closing tag
       (?<fctag>   </[^>]*+> )      # foreign closing tag
       (?<comment> <!-- .*? --> )
       (?<cdata>   \Q<![CDATA[\E .*? ]]> )
       (?<tag>     <(\w++)[^>]*+> (?> [^<]++ | (?&all)
                 | (?!</\g{-1})(?&fctag) )*+ </\g{-1}> )
       (?<all>     \s++ | (?&tag) | (?&comment) | (?&cdata) | (?&sctag) ) 
       (?<sub>     (?> (?&all) | (?&fctag) )++ )
                   ) `xsi;

my $search = join '(?&sub)', @wordlist;

if ($content =~ /$patterns (?<res>$search?)/xsi) {
    print "\n$+{res}";
} else {
    print "\nnot found";
}
```

The idea is to split string_2 on white characters to obtain a wordlist. Each character in the wordlist that is not a letter or a digit is escaped (if needed) and surrounded with an optional reference to the subpattern `(?&all)?`. Then all items are joined with `(?&all)`.

However there is probably a cleaner way using an html parser.

Comment: Thanks Casimir, but I am getting an error while copying to editor, 
Kindly see the following link for screenshot  
http://postimg.org/image/6ts99wzlh/

Comment: @user3354853: I just change the script to avoid this kind of match: "Wieder   vereinigung" => "Wiedervereinigung" and to deal with consecutive punctuation characters.

Comment: Using this code, Can I find single line in whole HTML document's content like the same way of matching string_1 and string_2 ?

Comment: @user3354853: what do you mean by "single line"?

Comment: sorry! not single line, I mean that can I find one paragraph in whole HTML document

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in two parts: finding and replacing.

1: find match, regardless of HTML tags (easy)

```
my $string_1="your big  string <H1>to</H1> found here";
my $string_2="string to found";
my $match_str = $string_1;
#cleanup HTML tags for matching
$match_str =~ s!<[^>]*>!!gis;
#check if match could be found
if ($match_str =~ m!$string_2!i){
   print "$string_2 found\n";
}
```

2: Try to extract the original string (hard). This may works.

```
use Data::Dumper;
my $string_1="your big  string <H1>to</H1> found here";
my $string_2="string to found";
my $se_string_2 = $string_2;
### replace every space with (?:\s*<[^>]*>\s*)+
$se_string_2 =~ s! !\(\?:\\s\*\<\[\^>\]\*\>\\s\*\)\+!gis;
print Dumper( $string_1,$string_2,$se_string_2);
#check if match could be found
while ($string_1 =~ s!($se_string_2)!!i){
   print "$string_2 found, string with tags: $1\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind help, your method gives me some ideas