# How to create HTML tags on matching strings using Perl

Tags: regex, perl

**string_1**

> < p class="paraind">< i>Erstens werden kulturelle Defizite bzw. ein geringes kulturelles Kapital der Migrantenfamilien angenommen, das unter Bezugnahme auf das kultursoziologisch **begr&#x00FC;ndete BORDIEU&#x2019;sche < i>Habituskonzept< /i> und seine These der &#x201A;kulturellen** Passung&#x2018; wegen der angenommenen Distanz der Migrantenfamilien zur deutschen (Mittelschicht-)Kultur f&#x00FC;r geringe Bildungschancen von Migrantenkinder verantwortlich sei. BORDIEU und PASSERON benutzen f&#x00FC;r diesen Vergleich des famili&#x00E4;ren kulturellen Kapitals mit dem der < i>Mittelschichtinstitution< /i>< a id="ch1_fn18" href="chapter1.html#cch1_fn18">< sup>18< /sup>< /a> der Schule den durchaus umstrittenen Begriff der &#x201A;kulturellen Passung&#x2018; (1971). Der Erkl&#x00E4;rungsansatz der kulturellen Herkunft als Ursache f&#x00FC;r Bildungs(miss)erfolg erscheint deswegen prinzipiell umstritten und quasiwissenschaftlich, weil viele der Herkunftskultur zugeschriebenen Eigenschaften sich oftmals als soziale Faktoren entpuppen, und weil die Unterstellung einer pauschal defizit&#x00E4;ren Lebenslage, Kultur und Sprachverm&#x00F6;gens nicht-deutscher Familien auf eine kulturalistischessentialistische, wenn nicht sogar diskriminierende Haltung verweist.< /p>

**string_2**

> begr&#x00FC;ndete BORDIEU&#x2019;sche Habituskonzept und seine These der &#x201A;kulturellen

You can see that **string_2** contents match with **string_1** (highlighted text) but only difference is **< i>** tag in **string_1**, So I can not match these two strings

I want to create all the tags from **string_1** to its corresponding texts in **string_2** to match both string,

Kindly somebody give any idea or solution for this

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create tags from one content to another content using PERL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23751208/how-to-create-tags-from-one-content-to-another-content-using-perl)

Comment: Miller, in your question link the subject is to create the missing tag with contents in another content.  But in this, I want to create tag for the word already in another string, Note: Only tag not with content, I think there is a differences, But really thank for your prompt reply

Comment: @user3354853 [It's "Perl", not "PERL".](http://learn.perl.org/faq/perlfaq1.html#Whats-the-difference-between-perl-and-Perl-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A less restrictive version of [`my regex solution`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23769804/1733163) to your [`previous question`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23751208/1733163) can solve this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string_1 = do {local $/; <DATA>};

my $string_2 = "begr&#x00FC;ndete BORDIEU&#x2019;sche Habituskonzept und seine These der &#x201A;kulturellen";

# Build a regex to match HTML interjected at whitespace
my $string2_re = join '(?:\s+|<.*?>)+', map quotemeta, split ' ', $string_2;

if ($string_1 =~ /($string2_re)/) {
    print "Matching = '$1'";
}

__DATA__
< p class="paraind">< i>Erstens werden kulturelle Defizite bzw. ein geringes kulturelles Kapital der Migrantenfamilien angenommen, das unter Bezugnahme auf das kultursoziologisch begr&#x00FC;ndete BORDIEU&#x2019;sche < i>Habituskonzept< /i> und seine These der &#x201A;kulturellen Passung&#x2018; wegen der angenommenen Distanz der Migrantenfamilien zur deutschen (Mittelschicht-)Kultur f&#x00FC;r geringe Bildungschancen von Migrantenkinder verantwortlich sei. BORDIEU und PASSERON benutzen f&#x00FC;r diesen Vergleich des famili&#x00E4;ren kulturellen Kapitals mit dem der < i>Mittelschichtinstitution< /i>< a id="ch1_fn18" href="chapter1.html#cch1_fn18">< sup>18< /sup>< /a> der Schule den durchaus umstrittenen Begriff der &#x201A;kulturellen Passung&#x2018; (1971). Der Erkl&#x00E4;rungsansatz der kulturellen Herkunft als Ursache f&#x00FC;r Bildungs(miss)erfolg erscheint deswegen prinzipiell umstritten und quasiwissenschaftlich, weil viele der Herkunftskultur zugeschriebenen Eigenschaften sich oftmals als soziale Faktoren entpuppen, und weil die Unterstellung einer pauschal defizit&#x00E4;ren Lebenslage, Kultur und Sprachverm&#x00F6;gens nicht-deutscher Familien auf eine kulturalistischessentialistische, wenn nicht sogar diskriminierende Haltung verweist.< /p>
```

Outputs:

```
Matching = 'begr&#x00FC;ndete BORDIEU&#x2019;sche < i>Habituskonzept< /i> und seine These der &#x201A;kulturellen'
```

Comment: Thanks Miller!, I cant match in another scenario: (eg: my string_1 = "<p class=\"para\">Kindern aus sozial benachteiligten Familien und Migrantenfamilien nachgedacht<a id=\"ch2_fn32\" href=\"chapter2.html#cch2_fn32\"><sup>32</sup></a>. Die als &#x201E;Lernprozess&#x201C; (BRATER et al. 2007: 23)</p>" ) I want to find string_2="milien und Migrantenfamilien nachgedacht. Die als &#x201E;Lernprozess&#x201C; (BRATER"

Comment: @user3354853 I'm glad that I was able to help.  Please note that I've demonstrated all of the tools that you'll need to make further enhancements to your processing goal.  Good luck.